# Why does this rock-paper-scissors almost always returns "tie(draw)"?

Tags: python

This program almost always returns "It's a draw(or tie)". Is it just me or is something wrong?
It is a Rock Paper Scissors program that does 10 rounds and shows the results in the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
# RockPaperScissors from Python
import random;
i = 1;
c = 0;
u = 0;
d = 0;
while i <= 10:
    userAnswer = input("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");
    computerAnswer = random.randint(1, 3);
    if (computerAnswer == 1): 
        computerAnswer = "rock";
    elif (computerAnswer == 2): 
        computerAnswer = "paper";
    else: 
        computerAnswer = "scissors";
    if (computerAnswer == "rock" and userAnswer == "paper"):
       print("You won(paper beats rock)");
       u = u + 1;
    elif (computerAnswer == "" and userAnswer == "paper"):  
        print("You lost(rock beats scissors)");
        c = c + 1;
    elif (computerAnswer == "paper" and userAnswer == "rock"):
        print("You lost(paper beats rock)");
        c = c + 1;
    elif (computerAnswer == "paper" and userAnswer == "scissors"):
        print ("You won(scissors beat paper)");
        u = u + 1;
    elif (computerAnswer == "scissors" and userAnswer == "paper"):
        print("You lost(scissors beats paper)");
        c = c + 1;
    elif (computerAnswer == "scissors" and userAnswer == "rock"):
        print("You won(rock beats scissors)");
        u = u + 1;
    else:
        print("It's a draw!");
        d = d + 1;

    if (i == 10):
        print("You won " + str(u) + " times.");
        print("You lost " + str(c) + " times.")
        print("It was a draw " + str(d) + " times.");
    i += 1;
```

The version of Python is 3.2(Python 3.2)

Comment: You should probably just write a better version which does not use all of these ifs. I'm not being mean - a more concise programme will be easier to debug.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what's going on in your code.  Before the `if (i==10)` line you can add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and then step through your code and print out what the variables are set to/run bits of code like `random.randint(1,3)`

Comment: you can use `computerAnswer = random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"])`, no need to assign a map of integers.

Comment: also, `u += 1` is equivalent to `u = u + 1`

Comment: With all those `;`, I first thought your program wasn't Python.

Comment: In the future, please do not edit the code in your question with the fixed version. That confuses people who come across the question later; they need to be able to see what went wrong in order to understand the answers you were given. SO is not just a place to get someone to fix your problem directly; it's a place for people to learn by seeing the problems others had (try it!).

Comment: Why not implementing **Rock-Paper-Scissor-Lizard-Spock** , it's far better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your test cases has a couple of errors.

```
elif (computerAnswer == "" and userAnswer == "paper"):  
    print("You lost(rock beats scissors)");
    c = c + 1;
```

Fix the `computerAnswer == ""` so that the computer's answer is rock instead of nothing and make the user's answer scissors instead of paper.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the first "elif" statement, the comparisons are wrong there, this distorts the probabilities.

I then just tried it a couple of times (Python 2.7.3) and the cases seem to come up in the correct proportion. Of the three cases (player1 wins, player2 wins, draw) each has three possibilities attached, so you'd expect to win 1/3, lose 1/3 and have a draw at 1/3 of the cases (however I made no statistical test...).